# in `%': Array can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError) Trying to reduce lines of Ruby Code

Tags: ruby, string

I got the above error when trying to reduce 5 lines to 1, using target.write:

```
target.write("%s \n %s \n %s \n") % [line1, line2, line3]
# target.write("\n")
# target.write(line2)
# target.write("\n")
# target.write(line3)
# target.write("\n")
```

The commented section ran(when the 1st line was `target.write(line1)`, but this does not.

Why isn't the very first line the same as writing the commented out six lines? here is the whole script:

```
filename = ARGV.first
script = $0

puts "We're going to erase #{filename}."
puts "If you don't want that hit control C"
puts "If you do want that hit execute or return"

print "? "
STDIN.gets

puts "Opening the file..."
target = File.open(filename, 'w')

puts "Truncating the file. Goodbye!"
target.truncate(target.size)

puts "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

print "line1: "; line1 = STDIN.gets.chomp()
print "line2: "; line2 = STDIN.gets.chomp()
print "line3: "; line3 = STDIN.gets.chomp()

puts "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write("%s \n %s \n %s \n") % [line1, line2, line3]
# target.write("\n")
# target.write(line2)
# target.write("\n")
# target.write(line3)
# target.write("\n")

puts "And finally we close it"
target.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closing paren on the `target.write` line is in the wrong place. Try

```
target.write("%s \n %s \n %s \n" % [line1, line2, line3])
```

Comment: geez, overlooking/over thinking simple things. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis are wrong. What you have:

```
target.write("%s \n %s \n %s \n") % [line1, line2, line3]
```

is equivalent to doing:

```
a = target.write("%s \n %s \n %s \n")
a % [line1, line2, line3]
```

Thus what you want is:

```
target.write("%s \n %s \n %s \n" % [line1, line2, line3])
```